# Visual studio: MSB307 error exited with code 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, flann

I am building **flann** from source. 
https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann

I configured and generated solution file using CMAKE. After building ALL_BUILD project, when I am trying to build INSTALL project, it gives the following error:

> ```
> > Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal "C:\Program
> > Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
> > if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd :cmEnd endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel
> > %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone :cmErrorLevel exit /b %1 :cmDone if
> > %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd :VCEnd" exited with code
> > 1.  INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  133
> ```

I tried to solve from stack overflow, but nothing works for me.
[Visual Studio: MSB3073 error exited with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457306/visual-studio-msb3073-error-exited-with-code-1)

During configuration using cmake, I clicked on the Add Entry button of the cmake gui, wrote CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX on the Name option, selected path from drop down list, and wrote folder location (different) on the value option.
Added value was>> D:\feasibilityAnalysis2020_3\Dpointcloud3Dvision\VSPCL3D\FLANN1

still showing error.

Environment:
Windows 10; 
Visual studio Community 2015;
CMAKE 3.14.1

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588065/3440745) to the question you refers to tells about setting proper `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable for CMake. What value you assign to that variable in your case?

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your comment. During configuration using cmake, I clicked on the Add Entry button of the cmake gui, wrote CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX on the Name option, selected path from drop down list, and wrote folder location (different) on the value option.

Comment: What **exact** value you assign to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`? Add this value to the **question post**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added value is explained to the question post